# OpenURI Open Throws 403 Forbidden

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-4, open-uri

I've written code that allows users to search for specific images through the Google Image Search API and then downloads those images using Carrierwave's remote image functionality.  We're getting bug reports though that certain URL's are throwing 403 Forbidden errors and we traced it back to

```
Kernel.open(url)
```

Scanning existing issues got me to "['open_http': 403 Forbidden (OpenURI::HTTPError) for the string “Steve_Jobs” but not for any other string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925591/open-http-403-forbidden-openurihttperror-for-the-string-steve-jobs-but)" which suggests that the problem is due to the missing User-Agent and so we added this to our call.

```
Kernel.open(url, 'User-Agent' => "Ruby/#{RUBY_VERSION}")
```

This resolved the issue in our dev environment but it had no effect at all in our production environment.  This is the most frustrating part.  My production environment (running on AWS EC2 Ubuntu 12.04) fails everytime and for far more URL's than my dev environment (OSX 9.5).  Both environments are running ruby 2.0.0-p353 and rails 4.0.5.

We've isolated several test URL's that we can consistently re-created this problem.

Example:  http://www.lowes.com/images/LCI/Planning/HowTos/ht_BuildaHomePlayground_kit.jpg

I'm running out of ideas, but it seems to be something specific to the AWS box (since it works in dev) so is it possible that AWS is using some sort of outbound filter/proxy or that Ubuntu 12.04 has a known issue with OpenURI?

Scouring the internet is starting to run out of options.

**UPDATE**

I have two AWS instances running, that were supposed to be identical to each other, but upon closer examination, one is running GNU/Linux 3.2.0-58-virtual and the code above works properly (thats my staging environment), and the other is running GNU/Linux 3.2.0-68-virtual and the code above fails (thats my production environment).  So the issue would seem to lie in whatever changed between 58 and 68.

For now, I'm switching my production and staging environments so that the issue is resolved, though it feels like a temporary and invalid fix since the staging environment is likely to be upgraded at some point thus landing us back at square one.

Comment: That agent definition isn't likely to work well in the wild, where systems that care about it will want to see one of the well-known browsers' signature.

Comment: `Kernel.open(url)` is wasting typing. After `require 'openuri'` you can simply `open(url)` which will do the same thing.

Comment: Fair point, I just copied it straight out of the Carrierwave code.  Regardless, I remain confused as to why it works on my Macbook but fails in Ubuntu running identical ruby versions.

Comment: Do all Lowes images fail? It's possible they're denying requests from that IP/IP block.

Comment: @ChrisHeald, that was going to be my next suggestion. Being blocked for too much activity is common. People don't stop to think about how fast a piece of Ruby code can spit out web requests and the impact that has on network connections and server loads.

Comment: " I'm switching my production and staging environments" If you've been banned, this will only result in both environments being banned. You *could* ask the webmaster or root at those sites if they have an API for accessing their images.